# how to stop adding 1 to a variable when it reaches 11?

Tags: python-3.7

```
out = 0
def catchoutp2():
    global out
    x = random.randint(1, 100)
    if x > 60:
       out += 1
```

## I want to stop adding when out reaches 11

Answer (score 0):

Just add a condition that `x > 60` and `out < 12`. Won't that work?

```
if x > 60 and out < 12:
```

Comment: no that won't work because when it reaches 11 i won't it to run a function

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean? I have changed the answer a bit, there was an error in there

Comment: i mean that i am creating a cricket game simulation and if out reaches 11 i ask them if you want play again or not.

Comment: that is a way broader question than the one you have posted though, without details of all the code it's very hard to answer